# Delete a file from a blob container in a Sata Share connection

Tags: azure, azure-data-share

o/

I have a Azure Data Share connection that I receive data in a parquet format everyday into my blob container. If a file is deleted in the source blob storage, it would be deleted on my side too?
I'm saying this because the company that sends the data deleted all data and create new ones with other names, so in this case I would have all the historical data, plus the new data right?
The connection it's set up as incremental

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When file systems, containers, or folders are shared in snapshot-based sharing, data consumers can choose to make a full copy of the share data. Or they can use the incremental snapshot capability to copy only new or updated files. The incremental snapshot capability is based on the last modified time of the files.

Existing files that have the same name are overwritten during a snapshot. **A file that is deleted from the source isn't deleted on the target**. Empty subfolders at the source aren't copied over to the target.

For more details, refer to [Share and receive data from Azure Blob Storage and Azure Data Lake Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-share/how-to-share-from-storage).